# VB script to process all files in a folder keeping original name

Tags: vbscript

I have a simple VBScript which removes 2 columns from a txt file. See below.

```
Dim fso, tsIn, tsOut, TheLine

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\test\file.txt")
Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\test\Output.txt", True)

Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
TheLine = tsIn.ReadLine
If InStr(1, TheLine, ",") > 0 Then
    TheLine = Left(TheLine, InStrRev(TheLine, ",") - 2)
End If
tsOut.WriteLine TheLine
Loop

tsIn.Close
tsOut.Close
Set tsIn = Nothing
Set tsOut = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

I am looking for it to do this for all files in the folder and create a output file for each one with the same name but followed by the date. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my updated code:

```
Dim fso, tsIn, tsOut, TheLine, f

today = Year(Date) & Right("00" & Month(Date), 2) & Right("00" & Day(Date), 2)

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\test").Files
tsOutName = fso.GetBaseName(f) & today & fso.GetExtensionName(f)
tsOutPath = fso.BuildPath(f.ParentFolder, tsOutName)

Set tsIn = f.OpenAsTextStream
Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile(tsOutPath, True)

Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream

TheLine = tsIn.ReadLine
If InStr(1, TheLine, ",") > 0 Then
TheLine = Left(TheLine, InStrRev(TheLine, ",") - 2)
End If
tsOut.WriteLine TheLine
Loop

tsIn.Close
tsOut.Close
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\test\file.txt")
Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\test\Output.txt", True)

Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
...
Loop

tsIn.Close
tsOut.Close
```

into this:

```
today = Year(Date) & Right("00" & Month(Date), 2) & Right("00" & Day(Date), 2)

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\test").Files
  tsOutName = fso.GetBaseName(f) & today & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(f)
  tsOutPath = fso.BuildPath(f.ParentFolder, tsOutName)

  Set tsIn = f.OpenAsTextStream
  Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile(tsOutPath, True)

  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
  ...
  Loop

  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get a error on line 3 when I try to run the code. I am getting a " required on this line..... For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\test").Files

Comment: @user2528157 Please show your updated code. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @user2528157 I told you to change the part I quoted in my answer, not to remove everything else. Add the other parts back to your script, particularly the creation of the `FileSystemObject` instance.